How to combine texture and normal map to create procedural paper/cloth material?
Let's say we want to create a shader (in Eevee, no displacement) to mimic crumpled paper or wrinkled cloth.
If we just use the paper or cloth texture with a noise texture + bump-node as normal map the result is poor as it looks like the texture (e.g. hex pattern) is just projected onto the noise.

A more realistic approach would make the texture get distorted/warped/bend by the noise.

My idea was to change the texture coordinate from $(u,v)$ to $(u,v) + c f(u,v) \nabla f(u,v)$,
where $c>0$ is a parameter, $f$ the noise and $\nabla f$ its bump map. That's prob. not correct and causes artefacts.
It kinda goes into the right direction, but surely I'm not the first to come up with this problem, so I'd appreciate any links or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure about the mathematical part of this, but what about mixing uv with normal map with a color mix node?:

